# Finding the maximum value within particular days for different items in a database

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have extracted security wise price details for more than 1300 securities in a year. Looks something like this.

It contains the following columns - Date Symbol Close for all the securities in one dataframe for about 200 trading days

I want to find whether the last price of security is maximum price within different time frames - 7 days, 25 days, 100 days etc. for all these 1300 securities. So let's say the close price today might be max of last 7 days but not 25 days. Then I would need True in 7 days Column and False in 25 days Column.

I am not able to figure out the loop for the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your entire data structure looks like but for a single security you could use `rolling()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close': [10,13,21,12,16,13,17,20,18,15,22,20]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20210301'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210302'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210303'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210304'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210305'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210308'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210309'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210310'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210311'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210312'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210315'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20210316')  ])
```

**df:**

```
            Close
2021-03-01  10
2021-03-02  13
2021-03-03  21
2021-03-04  12
2021-03-05  16
2021-03-08  13
2021-03-09  17
2021-03-10  20
2021-03-11  18
2021-03-12  15
2021-03-15  22
2021-03-16  20
```

Using rolling you can get the `max()` in this case of the last n values:

```
df['Close'].rolling(4).max()

2021-03-01     NaN
2021-03-02     NaN
2021-03-03     NaN
2021-03-04    21.0
2021-03-05    21.0
2021-03-08    21.0
2021-03-09    17.0
2021-03-10    20.0
2021-03-11    20.0
2021-03-12    20.0
2021-03-15    22.0
2021-03-16    22.0
```

With that you can get the True/False entries that you desire (I use 2, 4 and 6 window sizes for illustration - you would need to adjust to 7, 25, 100, etc):

```
df['max2'] = df['Close'] == df['Close'].rolling(2).max()
df['max4'] = df['Close'] == df['Close'].rolling(4).max()
df['max6'] = df['Close'] == df['Close'].rolling(6).max()
```

**df:**

```
            Close   max2   max4   max6
2021-03-01     10  False  False  False
2021-03-02     13   True  False  False
2021-03-03     21   True  False  False
2021-03-04     12  False  False  False
2021-03-05     16   True  False  False
2021-03-08     13  False  False  False
2021-03-09     17   True   True  False
2021-03-10     20   True   True  False
2021-03-11     18  False  False  False
2021-03-12     15  False  False  False
2021-03-15     22   True   True   True
2021-03-16     20  False  False  False
```

Important to note that a `rolling(6)`, for example, will need 6 previous values to work in this case.  If 6 are not present yet a NaN is returned.  In other words, you will get False until you have 6 values to look back on. Though this can be configured with the `min_periods` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this one and see if it is working as expected. Looking good based on what I am seeing. Thanks a lot.